# Zbar Raspberry Pi Installation

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, zbar

I'm attempting to install zbar on my raspberry pi. I build the source by entering:

./configure
make
make install

After the install finishes, I enter python and attempt to import zbar. Doing this results in a segmentation fault.

Any ideas on what could be the issue?

Comment: no errors or warnings from make?

Comment: That's correct, everything seems to make just fine.

Comment: We have a site for [raspberrypi.se] now, you might have a better chance of getting an answer there.

Comment: Should/Can I move this post over there, or is it ok to keep it here?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you want a version that isn't in the repository, do:

```
apt-get install python-zbar
```

Comment: and is there a version in rapsbian repository? what is the package name? I mean zbar inself... not python wrappers.